# Render UI component in GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es

I met a problem with OpenGL integration. The requirement is to show a complex UI component on top of map (rendered by OpenGL engine). And this **UI component should pin to specific point** while map is moving.

One straight forward solution is to render the complex UI component by OpenGL Engine. But it takes a lot of effort to layout/render and event handling.

Another way I come up is to put an overlay UI component on top of OenpGL map, and make it moving while map is panning. As you know, for GLSurfaceView, the rendering happens in a separate thread while UI component renders in main UI thread. I can make it functionally work. But **it always be a little shift between UI component and map while panning since they are actually running in two thread**.

Do you have any idea to overcome this problem?

Two directions I am thinking are:

1. any way to render OpenGL map in UI thread?
2. How to render a common UI component in GL thread.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, probably not.

As for 2, you can't touch any ui component outside of ui-thread.

Your problem is very much like Vsync-Mouse lag problems. And as far as my limited knowledge about it, they solve that problem(well, not solve completely but...) by keeping last N location of the mouse and predicting the N+1 th one by extrapolation. You can implement something like this.

I also suggest you to look at multi-threaded rendering stuff. As literally this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. This is an idea I never think about. In theory, I am able to have same inertia algorithm as OpenGL engine. Let me see how hard it is.

Comment: By Vsync-Mouse lag problems, are you referring to the visual cursor position? That is generally solved by using a "hardware cursor." The hardware cursor is a special hardware/driver feature that accepts the cursor position and will overlay the cursor at said position *every time* it pushes something out to the display (once per-VBLANK interrupt).

Comment: Yes, I mean cursor position. Actually hardware cursor is one of the solutions but still not smooth as it should. See when VSync is enabled lets say your render completed in 1 millisecond, and VSync kicks in every 16 milliseconds. Now there is a 15 milliseconds gap between your rendered frame and what user see. There is game engines that use extrapolation even for hardware cursors by manipulating cursor position. But you are also right, I wasn't thinking about hardware cursor.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am looking into the VSync doc to understand more about it. Will do some experiment and update you the result.